# Implementar una clase con un protocolo en swift

Tags: array, ios, swift, string, xcode

Estoy Tratando de implementar una **class** que debería darme el estado del tiempo, me piden una cadena como parámetro y también un *completion* y exactamente es allí en donde me pierdo sobre como implementarla.

Intente llamarla mediante  **weatherDataWith** para mostrar la información en mi *UI* pero no lo logro efectivamente.

Aquí dejo la clase a la que hago referencia.

**NOTA:** Dicha clase no puede ni debe ser modificada.

Soy un poco novato en esto así que disculpen si no soy claro.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

typealias CityCompletion = (city:CityData) -> Void

struct ForecastData {
    var temperature:Int!
    var minimumTemperature:Float!
    var maximumTemperature:Float!
    var time:NSDate!
    var weatherDescription:String!
    var weatherCode:Int!
    var background:UIImage?
    var icon:UIImage!
}

struct CityData {
    var name:String?
    var countryISO:String?
    var forecasts:[ForecastData]!
}

enum WeatherUnits : String {
    case Metric = "&units=metric"
    case Imperial = "&units=imperial"
    case Standard = ""
}


class WeatherBase {
    static let sharedInstance = WeatherBase()
    var apiKey:String! = "b7507934ec3cef25f35b0f985ddb429c"
    var unit:WeatherUnits = .Metric

    private init() { }

    func iconWeather(code:Int) -> (icon:UIImage, background:UIImage) {
        switch code {
        case 200..<300:
            return (UIImage(named: "tormenta-icon")!, UIImage(named: "tormenta")!)
        case 300..<400:
            return (UIImage(named: "llovizna-icon")!, UIImage(named: "llovizna")!)
        case 500..<600:
            return (UIImage(named: "lluvia-icon")!, UIImage(named: "llovizna")!)
        case 600..<700:
            return (UIImage(named: "nieve-icon")!, UIImage(named: "nieve")!)
        case 700..<800:
            return (UIImage(named: "niebla-icon")!, UIImage(named: "niebla")!)
        case 800:
            return (UIImage(named: "soleado-icon")!, UIImage(named: "soleado")!)
        case 801..<810:
            return (UIImage(named: "nublado-icon")!, UIImage(named: "nublado")!)
        default:
            return (UIImage(named: "soleado-icon")!, UIImage(named: "soleado")!)
        }
    }

    func weatherDataWith(cityName:String, completion:CityCompletion) {
        let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=\(cityName)&mode=json&appid=\(apiKey)\(unit.rawValue)&lang=es"
        let escapedAddress = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

        Alamofire.request(.GET, escapedAddress!).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
            if let result = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
                var city = CityData()
                city.name = result["city"]!["name"] as? String
                city.countryISO = result["city"]!["country"] as? String

                var forecasts:[ForecastData] = []
                for f in result["list"] as! NSArray {
                    var forecast = ForecastData()
                    forecast.temperature = Int(round(f["main"]!!["temp"] as! Float))
                    forecast.maximumTemperature = (f["main"]!!["temp_max"] as! Float)
                    forecast.minimumTemperature = (f["main"]!!["temp_min"] as! Float)

                    forecast.time = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: (f["dt"] as! Double))

                    if let weather = f["weather"] as? NSArray {
                        print(weather)
                        forecast.weatherCode = weather[0]["id"] as! Int
                        forecast.weatherDescription = weather[0]["description"] as! String
                    }

                    let images = self.iconWeather(forecast.weatherCode)

                    forecast.icon = images.icon
                    forecast.background = images.background

                    forecasts.append(forecast)
                }

                city.forecasts = forecasts
                completion(city: city)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo cual es tu problema... La clase parece que ya la tienes implementada. ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona o lo que no sabes hacer?

Comment: yo estoy con el mismo tema... : ) vos pudiste solucionarlo???

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que tu problema es este:

```
weatherDataWith(cityName: "Madrid") { (cityData) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Aquí modificas la vista.
    }
}
```

La explicación de esto es que la vista corre en el hilo principal. Cuando haces una llamada a un web service, que es lo que hace Alamofire, estás abriendo un hilo en background y desde ese hilo no puedes modificar la vista. Para eso usamos el `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` ese bloque de código se ejecuta **asíncronamente** en el **hilo principal**.

Si tienes dudas acerca de la **concurrencia** te recomiendo que leas como funciona un procesador multi core. Es un mundo apasionante la concurrencia pero muy difícil, tanto de entender como de manejar.

Comment: No tengo ni idea de Swift. pero los terminos de opiniones como "me parece" no dan mucha credibilidad. Te sugiero que reformules la frase para que al menos parezca que estás seguro de ti mismo xD

Comment: @lois6b pongo me parece por que no podría asegurar que sea eso lo que está preguntando. Creeme, no es por que dude de mi mismo.

Comment: Pues para eso puedes preguntarle en los comentarios bajo su pregunta :P

Comment: @lois6b dejemos que el usuario sea quien estime mi respuesta. Creo que le servirá sea o no sea su pregunta. Y creo en un 80% que mi respuesta soluciona su problema.